# Is local Storage suitable for the storage data of phonegap developement

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage

I'm now developing a phonegap app and I plan to save all users' userid, email address and password in local storage, I don't need a big database and I need to run the app in eclipse emulator, I just need a storage to save data and then I could retrieve them when users sign up, so I'm wondering is local storage suitable for my use?

Comment: For development purposes you can do this, but don't do this in a production app. You should check, how to implement an OAuth server/client to work around this and keep your app and User data safe.

Comment: @Philip It is unnecessary for me to concern safety issue as it's for school project, I just need to ensure data is stored when users sign up and I can retrieve them when they sign in. Is it doable by Local Storage?

Comment: From the one app instance yes. It is not globally managable though, nor is it adviced to take such an approach. Note it is also possible to clear all browser data storage on a device, meaning if a user clears the browser data storage, the user will have to start over as a new user. Again not a good approach, even conceptually for a school project.

Comment: I will not repeat this, just follow @War10ck comment. It's possible, if it's ok for you, but not suggested!

Comment: @War10ck Oh then is there any better suggest, websql? Cuz I'm seeking a easy way to establish the database

Comment: Unfortunately, `WebSQL` and `SQLite` will still exist client side. You'll run into the same problems as with localStorage. To effectively set up this system, you'll need a server side language, and a database to store user accounts and optionally user data. Everything in the app needs to be synced with the server. Consider the server the master source and always fetch from there when you restart the app.

Comment: @War10ck Is mysql suited? Since I need to present on eclipse emulator,does it work on emulator?

Comment: You can use mysql as your backend db. I'm not sure if it will run off of eclipse though. I'm not too familiar with eclipse. Normally, you would run this off of a web server.

Comment: have you tried using cordova sqlite plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you plan on storing information worth 5MB(cause local-storage supports upto 5MB) there would be no better choice than Local-Storage.